# How do I add data to an Excel chart using Python and win32com.client

Tags: excel, python-3.x, win32com

I have been looking at here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/object-model-excel-vba-reference

I created a chart in Excel manually and recorded the macro. Using that I am trying to navigate which methods to use. In my code below, ch is an embedded chart object in the worksheet. According to the above link, it should have a method called SetSourceData which takes Range as a required parameter.

```
import win32com.client as wc

xl = wc.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add() 
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
ws.Name = 'New Sheet'

ws.Cells(5,5).Value = 1
ws.Cells(6,5).Value = 1
ws.Cells(5,6).Value = 1
ws.Cells(6,6).Value = 1

ch = ws.ChartObjects().Add(100, 100, 100, 100)

#everything above works fine. problem is I can't add data to my chart.

ch.SetDataSource("E5:F5")
```

When I run the above, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-5b5d1a6d3109> in <module>()
     30 ws.Cells(6,6).Value = 1
     31 
---> 32 ch.SetDataSource("E5:F5")
     33 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    525 
    526                 # no where else to look.
--> 527                 raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
    528 
    529         def __setattr__(self, attr, value):

AttributeError: Add.SetDataSource
```

Is there a way to show which methods are available when I import win32com.client? Right now, I have to keep going to the MS website and dig through each method for chart creating/formatting, which is not efficient, but instructive I must admit.

Comment: Your `ch` is a `ChartObject`, which is just a container for a `Chart` so it can be placed on a worksheet.  `ch.Chart` is the chart itself, so try `ch.Chart.SetDataSource("E5:F5")`.  As to your other question: if you're using COM then anything available via VBA should also be available to your automation code (possibly with slight syntactical differences)

Comment: Thanks Tim. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I get <unknown>.SetSourceData

Comment: Well that was my best guess...

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I have been playing with xlsxwriter and for my purposes it works great and very easy to use. The only downside is that it cannot modify existing Excel files, which I can live with. But the reason I wanted to use win32com.client was because it is the approach I had taken before when I was using LabVIEW. I am trying to switch over to automating my data processing using Python.

Comment: OK.  BTW I just realized it's `SetSourceData` not `SetDataSource` so that may explain your problems...

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It's a typo when I posted. In my code I checked and used SetSourceData, and get the same error

Comment: SetSourceData requires a qualified range. In VBA it would be `<somechart>.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("E5:F5")`. Note that SetSourceData doesn't add data to a chart, it defines the whole data range of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

```
ch.SetDataSource(Source=ws.Range('E5:F5'))
```